# How to write inputs into a binary file and read it in c?

Tags: c, file, binary, bin

Recently I am working on a beginner projects. But I was stuck for days without knowing how to update a file. Then I found I can do it with binary files, so I started using binary files instead of normal files. But now when I write into binary files it works (I assume), but when I read from it, it gives me `segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Here is my structs

```
struct date{  // structure for dates
    int mm, dd, yyyy;
};

struct {
    char *initials, *name, *email, *acc_type;  // unchangeable values 
    char id_num[11], occupation[25], address[100];  // changeable values
    int phone, acc_num, balance;
    struct date birth_day;  // structure for birth day
} new_acc;
```

Here is my writing function...

```C
void create_new(void)
{
    // Allocating memory for each member in struct
    new_acc.name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(new_acc.name));  
    new_acc.initials = (char *) malloc(sizeof(new_acc.initials));
    new_acc.email = (char *) malloc(sizeof(new_acc.email));
    new_acc.acc_type = (char *) malloc(sizeof(new_acc.acc_type));

    system("clear");
    puts("Answer the questions to make a account");

    time_t l;  // To generate a number
    srand((unsigned) time(&l));  // Generating a random number to account number
    new_acc.acc_num = l;  // Assign l value to acc_num var in struct

    printf("Enter your full name: ");
    scanf(" %100[^\n]", new_acc.name);  // scan for name, 100 characters, and also accepting spaces

    printf("Enter your name with initials: ");
    scanf(" %100[^\n]", new_acc.initials);

    printf("Enter your birthday (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
    scanf(" %d %d %d", &new_acc.birth_day.mm, &new_acc.birth_day.dd, &new_acc.birth_day.yyyy)

    printf("Enter your address: ");
    scanf(" %100[^\n]", new_acc.address);

    printf("Enter your phone number: ");
    scanf(" %10d", &new_acc.phone);

    printf("Enter your id number: ");
    scanf(" %10[0-9a-zA-Z]", new_acc.id_num);

    printf("Enter your occupation: ");
    scanf(" %50[^\n]", new_acc.occupation);

    printf("Enter your email address:");
    scanf(" %s", new_acc.email);

    printf("Enter the account type:\n");
    printf("\t#Saving\n\tFixed (1 year)\n\tFixed (2 year)\n\tFixed (3 year)\n");
    scanf(" %20s", new_acc.acc_type);

    printf("Enter amount to deposite: $");
    scanf(" %d", &new_acc.balance);

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("employees", "a");  // Opening file in append mode 

    if (fp == NULL)  // If  file couldn't open 
        puts("Cannot open a file...");

    // Here, I also used while loop, but I don't know how to break it so I used for loop
    for (int i = 0; i <= 12; ++i)  // Looping 12 times  
        fwrite(&new_acc, sizeof(new_acc), 1, fp);  // writting to file 

     fclose(fp);  // Closing file

    // freeing memory after use
    free(new_acc.name);
    free(new_acc.initials);
    free(new_acc.email);
    free(new_acc.acc_type);

    int out;
    printf("Successfully created a account!\nYour account number is %d\n", new_acc.acc_num);
    printf("Press 1 to exit, and 0 to go to main menu...");
    scanf("%d", &out);

    switch (out){
    case 1:
        exit(0);
        break;
    case 0:
        menu();
        break;
    }
}
```

And here my reading coding snippet also

```C
FILE *fp; 
    fp = fopen("employees", "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
        puts("Cannot open a file...");

    for (int i = 0; i <= 12; ++i)
        fread(&new_acc, sizeof(new_acc), 1, fp);

    fclose(fp);

    printf("%d\n", new_acc.acc_num); // It only prints acc_num
    // After that it gives me segmentation fault 
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.name);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.initials);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.birth_day);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.address);
    printf("%d\n", new_acc.phone);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.id_num);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.occupation);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.email);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.acc_type);
    printf("%d\n", new_acc.balance);
```

All I don't sure correct is writing and reading bin file...

Comment: Seems like you are just writing the contents of your account struct to the file. Think about what the 'name', 'initials' etc. fields are. They are just char pointers pointing to memory you allocated before. When you write those to file, you just store the address, the pointer points to. Instead, you want to store the actual content of these strings. Also, Whats up with that loop in your write function?

Comment: So is that means when I use ```fread``` and ```fwrite``` I don't have to use ```&``` ternary operator

Comment: No. You either have to use char arrays of fixed size in your struct instead of allocating memory for the strings dynamically, then you can just write the struct to file. Or you write the actual strings (at the moment you are just saving the *pointers* to the strings) to the file aswell. Then when reading from file, you read the struct, then read the strings and reinitalize the pointers to the strings so they point to the strings you just read from file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wrong at writing into bin file and also reading from it.

First of all I need to thank to @lulle.

- As he mentioned in comments I changed `char*` in struct into `char` arrays.

```C
char initials[80], name[250], email[100], acc_type[25];
```

- And I also change file mode. I use `ab` to writing snippet. And `rb` in reading snippet.
- And I changed my writing snippet.

Here I looped over 12 times, this wrote every record 12 time. Sad ah?
This happened because I used just address of struct `&new_acc` in `fwrite`. If you use just address of a struct in ``` fwrite`` or ``` fread``` it will write your whole struct. That's what happened to me. I wrote the whole struct 12 time.

```C
for (int i = 0; i <= 12; ++i)  // Looping 12 times  
        fwrite(&new_acc, sizeof(new_acc), 1, fp);  // writting to file
```

So instead of looping I changed it into this

```C
fwrite(&new_acc, sizeof(new_acc), 1, fp); \\ This line will write whole struct
```

But if you want to use members of struct instead of a whole struct, you are free to use a loop. Here is a example. This example is same as above one. But remember to use `i` or any variable that you used in `for` loop when writing to file. Instead of `i`, if you used member name, It will also write 12 times (or as far as you are looping...)

```C
for (int i = 0; i <= 12; ++i)  // Looping 12 times  
        fwrite(&new_acc.[i], sizeof(new_acc.[i]), 1, fp);  // writting to file
```

- And the same thing happened to reading part (I guess...).
  So I changed the code snippet like below

```C
    FILE *fp; 
    fp = fopen("employees", "rb");

    if (fp == NULL)
        puts("Cannot open a file...");

    int i = 0;
    while(fread(&new_acc, sizeof(new_acc), 1, fp) != 0){  /* use fread one time */
    printf("%d\n", new_acc.acc_num);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.name);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.initials);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.birth_day);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.address);
    printf("%d\n", new_acc.phone);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.id_num);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.occupation);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.email);
    printf("%s\n", new_acc.acc_type);
    printf("%d\n", new_acc.balance);    
    
    ++i;
    }

    fclose(fp);
```